# Why is LINQ sorting my array?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm having the following code:

```
int[] numbers = new int[] { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 };
int i = 0;
var query =
     from n in numbers
     select ++i;

foreach (var n in query)
    Console.WriteLine("number = {0}, counter = {1}", n, i);
```

Why is the output sorted in increasing order even when I'm not giving it an `orderby`?

```
number = 1, counter = 1
number = 2, counter = 2
number = 3, counter = 3
number = 4, counter = 4
number = 5, counter = 5
number = 6, counter = 6
number = 7, counter = 7
number = 8, counter = 8
number = 9, counter = 9
number = 10, counter = 10
```

Comment: `query` is selecting `i` not `n`.

Comment: Notice there is no value 0 in your output?

Comment: And a 10 that wasn't in the underlying data source.

Comment: May I ask why is this question upvoted?

Comment: Seems like a good interview questions :)

Answer (score 6):

```
select ++i
```

You're selecting `i`, not the values in your array.

Answer (score 1):

Something interesting that your question accidentally demonstrates is how LINQ queries are lazily evaluated in C#. Notice the fact that your query expression has a side effect: it increments the `i` variable on each iteration. The laziness of evaluation is given away by the fact that the `counter =` output increments on each iteration.

Compare the output of your program to the one posted below. The only difference is that I turn the query into an array before I iterate over it.

```
int[] numbers = new int[] { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 };
int i = 0;
var query =
     from n in numbers
     select ++i;

foreach (var n in query.ToArray())
    Console.WriteLine("number = {0}, counter = {1}", n, i);
```

**Output**

```
number = 1, counter = 10
number = 2, counter = 10
number = 3, counter = 10
number = 4, counter = 10
number = 5, counter = 10
number = 6, counter = 10
number = 7, counter = 10
number = 8, counter = 10
number = 9, counter = 10
number = 10, counter = 10
```